# when to create a method for a service?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Let's say I have a service called BookService, and I have method called `GetAllBooks`, `GetBookById`, and so on. Now I want to get all books that are recently modified, so do I need another method? or should I use `GetAllBooks().Where(....)`?

And in the code below, is there a difference between `GetBooksByAuthorA` and `GetBooksByAuthorB`?

```
public List<Book> GetAllBooks()
{
   return _context.Books.ToList();
}

public List<Book> GetBooksByAuthorA(string author)
{
   return _context.Books.Where(a => a.Author == author);
}

public List<Book> GetBooksByAuthorB(string author)
{
   return GetAllBooks().Where(a => a.Author == author);
}
```

PS: The code above is not tested and I only write it as an example of what point I'm trying to tell.

Comment: `GetBooksByAuthorB` will load every single book from the database, then filter it in memory. It's a bad approach.

Answer (score 0):

Create another method that filters the results to only those records you're interested in.

Once you call `ToList()`, the query you've been building is executed and all matching records are returned. So you definitely would not want to call `GetAllBooks()` if you're only interested in a subset of books.

```
public List<Book> GetBooksByAuthorA(DateTime modifiedDate)
{
  return _context.Books.Where(a => a.ModifiedDate > modifiedDate).ToList();
}
```

One other consideration. Unless you're calling these methods all over the place, I'm not sure you need to be creating a separate method for each query.

At the point in your program where you decide you want a list of books by a particular author after a particular date, just create a new context and define your query.

```
List<Book> books;
using (var context = new YourDbContext())
{
  books = context.Books.Where(a => a.Author == author && a.ModifiedDate > modDate).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I actually using service and repository. what do you think if I add a method like `public IQueryable<Book> Table() { return _context.Set<Book>(); }`, then used it like `books = _bookService.Table().Where(a => a.Author == author && a.ModifiedDate > modDate).ToList();` because I only call this query once.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rob said, the difference is that _context.Books is [IQueryable](https://blog.falafel.com/understanding-ienumerable-iqueryable-c/) meaning the filter will be run *on the database*. GetBooksByAuthorB will load every single book from the database, then filter it *in memory*.

If you are fetching records from remote databases IQueryable should be used. It constructs the query using an Expression Tree. On the other hand in the IEnumerable  the query is constructed using delegates.

**Summary**: GetBooksByAuthorA is the way to go.

Comment: you're not adding much to that comment i'd say ... ?